# Handling an array of input values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to be able to handle an array of inputs using reactjs. For example, the following text field

```
<input type="text" value="" name="test[]" />
```

Here's the code I have

```
render () {
            var ret = [];
            var x = 0;
            var name = val + "[]";
            var v = this.state.course[val];

            for (x = 0; x < v.length; x++) {
                var label = val + " " + x;
                var vv = this.state.course[val][x];
                input = <input type="text" name={name} value={vv} onChange={(event) => {
                    var newCourse = {...this.state.course};
                    newCourse[val][x] = event.target.value;
                    this.setState({course: newCourse})
                }} key={val}/>;

                ret.push(<div>
                    <label>{label}</label><br/><br/>
                    {input}
                </div>);
            }
}
```

The problem with the code is that when I edit a text field with a name test[], it adds another text field instead of editing that specific text field. How do I handle an array of text inputs in react?

Comment: It's hard to follow those `ret += "</div>";`. It'll be easier to help if you just say _WHAT_ you wanna accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're using string concatenation which makes it a little hard to see what's going on but based I what I understood here is my implementation:

```
function updateAt(index, value, arr) {
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, index), 
    value, 
    ...arr.slice(index + 1, arr.length)
  ];
}

function Output({ name, list }) {
  return (
    <pre style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>
      <span>name: {name + "\n"}</span>
      <span> list: {list.join(" - ")}</span>
    </pre>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  let [state, setState] = React.useState({
    courses: {
      courseA: ["section 1", "section 2", "section 3"],
      courseB: ["section 1", "section 2", "section 3"]
    }
  });

  let courses = Object.entries(state.courses);

  return (
    <div>
      {courses.map(([course, list]) => (
        <>
        <div>
          {list.map((v, index) => (
            <input
              type="text"
              name={course}
              value={v}
              onChange={e => {
                let { value } = e.target;
                setState(s => ({
                  ...s,
                  courses: {
                    ...s.courses,
                    [course]: updateAt(index, value, s.courses[course])
                  }
                }));
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <Output name={course} list={list} />
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see the actual sandbox at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sfgfjy)